# Windows - get warned when a file is created

Tags: java, windows

I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible, but I would like to do the following:
When a file is created in a certain folder (Windows), my program should respond. I'd like to let Windows call a callback method when a file is created.

Another option is of course just use a loop and constantly check if a new file is in the folder, but I'd like to know it instantly, so a callback method would be much more efficient.

Is this possible? The language is not important, although Java is preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Java nio 2 (available in Java 1.7 +), you can ["watch" a directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) and get notified when that directory changes.

The method proposed in the tutorial linked above uses the [`WatchService` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) contains a `FileAlterationListener` wich has a `onDirectoryChange`method. Can be an alternative if Java 1.7 is not available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to Java, then you could use very convenient [FileSystemWatcher](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-the-net-filesystemwatcher-object-to-monitor-directory-changes-in-c/6165137) in C# or VisualBasic. It will allow you to watch all kinds of events which can occur in folder and it's quite easy to implement it.